# Export graphics in parallel

Tags: export, parallelization

I run a heavy simulation, using `NDSolve` and the [method of lines](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html). This means that the result of `NDSolve` is a list of, say, 400-1000 interpolation functions with many interpolation points. The whole thing can weigh up to 4GB.

As it is, this poses no problem. The challenge is when I try to make a movie out the simulation. I do the following: I have a function

```
snapshot[sol_,t_]:=GraphicsGrid[{Plot[...],Plot[..],...}]
```

which take the result of `NDSolve` (what I call `sol`) and a specific time `t`, and makes some plots of the simulation at that time. Then, I export these graphics with something like

```
Table[
  Export["~/tmp/" <> IntegerString[k, 10, 4] <> ".png",snapshot[sol, tList[[k]] ],
{k, 1, n}]
```

where `tList` is a list of times. Then I can make a movie out of the images with an external program (`ffmpeg`).

The problem is that exporting the graphics like this takes a lot of time and I want to run it in parallel. Using `ParallelTable` is very bad, because it creates a local copy of the very heavy variable `sol` in all subkernels, and this immediately freezes my computer. I had no luck with `ParallelSubmit` or the like. Any ideas?

***EDIT***

In response to all the commenters:

1. The plot is indeed local in the time variable.
2. I tried converting the `InterpolatingFunction`s to an numerical array. It saves some memory (a factor of ~50) but that's not enough - Still if you duplicate the data 1000 times (for 1000 frames) you'll be in bad shape.

Basically, what I want is to send requests to **multiple processors**, but that will all run **on the same kernel**. This way you don't have to duplicate I thought it was possible because in MATLAB I do that naturally with the `parfor` command (or, at least, I think that's what I'm doing).

Comment: If you sequentially generate your graphics (which will not be that memory-heavy) e.g. with `Table` and parallelize the `Export` of those afterwards, you should be fine. But this will only save time spent on `Export`, obviously.

Comment: @YvesKlett The problem is not with `snapshot[...]` but rather with `sol`.

Comment: Perhaps I am not getting this, but if `Export` itself (not the `snapshot[sol,...]` part) slows you down, then precompute a `List` of graphics and parallelize the `Export` of those graphics as mentioned above, e.g. with a `ParallelMap`or similar.

Comment: @yohbs: I think you should be somewhat more specific about what you plot. Do you need all of the 400-1000 interpolating functions for one `snapshot` call? If you only need a few of them you could try to only distribute what you need. Another thing I have done in similar situations is to deconstruct the interpolating functions and store the result in a large (packed) numeric array. Working with that is much more efficient (both concerning memory and runtimes) and usually the information you loose isn't relevant, especially for plotting purposes...

Comment: @Albert I would like to see an example of your packed array method.

Comment: If the `Graphics` in `snapshot` are local in the time variable, maybe you can pick the required values of `t` beforehand, put the required quantities for those times `t` into a list `solDiscrete` and work with that instead of `sol`. Then you could break that `solDiscrete` into chunks more easily than working with the `InterpolatingFunction`. Just an idea...

Comment: Someone may correct me, but my experience with `Export`ing graphics tells me that all the rendering is done by the Front End, and the parallelization commands can only send things to different kernels.  The Front End (through v8, and maybe v9 is different) does not parallelize any computations.  I would love to know I'm wrong, because I've wished to do similar things.

Comment: Actually, I may be wrong...I just tried parallel `Export`s and two front ends and two kernels fired up...

Comment: @AlbertRetey, and others - I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `SetSharedVariable` -- maybe?

Comment: @MichaelE2 see my answer - this confirms multiple frontend instances for rendering/export, at least for PNGs.

Comment: Since exporting in parallel works, your real issue seems to be not with `Export`, but with parallel generation of your solutions?

Comment: @yohbs: I think your questions is still not specific enough. I would guess that you apply the "method of lines" yourself (and don't use the corresponding internal method of `NDSolve`). If that's correct then you could extract all grid coordinates and values and only pass those to the plotting functions (and corresponding kernels) that are needed. I'm sure people will provide solutions for that if you tell us more about your solutions and what kind of plot you do, as usual a simplified working example helps tons...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: my "packed array method" isn't something very smart, I'm just using "ValuesOnGrid" and "Coordinates" of the resulting interpolating functions to extract the values on the gridpoints. Then I ensure these large numeric arrays are packed arrays and do any further processing with those. The percise details on what I store and how that data is arranged depends a little on the problem and the further processing, so it's not general enough to provide something without a specific example...

Comment: @Albert thanks.

Comment: @yohbs: one more thing: you will only need as many copies of the data as you have parallel Kernels. So if you managed to reduce the size by a factor ~50 you should be able to distribute that to about 50 parallel Kernels, which most probably is much more than your hardware will run in parallel. I would expect  that should solve your problem, can you explain why you think that it doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

Only a partial answer (excluding memory issues), but... `Export`ing in parallel seems to work (here with version 9 in Win 7 64bit):

```
gfx = Table[PolarPlot[Sin[3 t*i], {t, 0, Pi}], {i, 1, 10}];

ParallelTable[Print[$KernelID]; 
 Export["test" <> ToString[i] <> ".png", gfx[[i]]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

See the `$KernelID` - seems to work in parallel. Also, a number of "Wolfram Mathematica 9.0 Server" windows show up and ("Mathematica.exe" processes in the task manager), plus related kernels.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.  I modified it to make it take long enough I could monitor the processes and processors: `ParallelTable[Print[$KernelID]; Export["test" <> ToString[i] <> ".png", Show[Table[Plot3D[k + Sin[3 t*i + \[Pi] i Cos[s]], {t, 0, Pi}, {s, 0,  Pi}], {k, 10}]]], {i, 1, 10}]`.  Each kernel computes a `Graphics3D` and sends it to a front-end, each process waits on the other.  You can see the switching in the (Mac) Activity Monitor.  I believe this is new.  When I tested it in v8, each kernel waited on the same, one and only, front-end process.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Did you use "Evaluation"->"Parallel kernel status" for that as well? I did not bother, but is comes in useful at times.

Comment: No, I wasn't aware of that option -- I mean, menu command.  Thanks.